# in this python script why isnt it subtracting like it suppose to?

Tags: python, if-statement, subtraction

forum, I was just doing this for giggles to see how much I had learned and I came across an issue...below is what I have written, why isn't it subtracting as its suppose to, is there something that I should take into consideration?

```
numbers = input("what number would you like to calculate? ")

print(numbers)
first = numbers[0]
second = numbers[1]
third = numbers[2]
for i in range(1,10):
    z = int(third) + (i * 3)
    if z >= 10:
        z = z - 10
    y = int(second) + (i * 2)
    if y >= 10:
        y = y - 10
    x = int(first) + (i * 1)
    if x >= 10:
        x = x - 10    
    print(x, y, z)
    i += 1
```

any input on this issue would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: You convert to an int to do the addition, but you are back to using the string version for the comparison to 10 as well as the substraction

Comment: Share the output what you expect and what you get. PS: i+=1 is superfluous, just as the parenthesis around i*x.

Comment: @jordanm What do you mean by, "using the string version for the comparison to 10"? The variables compared to 10 are `x`, `y`, and `z`, which are all integers.

Comment: @jjramsey You are correct, I misread

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, though I am not sure what output do you expect. One issue what I've noticed is that you are not allowed to used whitespace in the input field. `numbers` is a string, and you use the first three characters of them. There is no integer version of ' ', so it will throw an error.

The output of the code is:

```
what number would you like to calculate? 123
123
2 4 6
3 6 9
4 8 2
5 0 5
6 2 8
7 4 11
8 6 14
9 8 17
0 10 20
```

This seems to be correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with it and added two more if statements to y and z and that gave me the result that I wanted. code is as follows:

```
numbers = input("what number would you like to calculate? ")
print(numbers)
first = numbers[0]
second = numbers[1]
third = numbers[2]
for i in range(1,10):
    z = int(third) + (i * 3)
    if z >= 10:
        z = z - 10
    if z >= 10:
        z = z - 10
    if z >= 10:
        z = z - 10
    y = int(second) + (i * 2)
    if y >= 10:
        y = y - 10
    if y >= 10:
        y = y - 10
    if y >= 10:
        y =y - 10
    x = int(first) + (i * 1)
    if x >= 10:
        x = x - 10    
    print(x, y, z)
    i += 1
```